How many clones are there on a countably infinite set?
I know that for a finite set $S$ with at least $3$ elements, there are continuum many clones over $S$. How about for a set which is countably infinite, like $\mathbb{N}$? Does it also have continuum many clones? Or is the cardinality even higher, perhaps $2$ to the continuum? Whatever the cardinality is, I want a proof that it has that cardinality.

What's a clone ?

@AAAL "Clone" is a terminology used in universal algebra. I don't know why it is called that, it is a weird name for what it describes, but it is the standard terminology.

Oh ok. This is really not my field then !

It is a theorem of Ivo Rosenberg that when $A$ is infinite, the number of clones on $A$ is $2^{2^{|A|}}$. In particular, there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many clones on a countably infinite set.
I found this by following a reference on the wikipedia page for clones.
